# Async CTP v3, MS Test and Thread.Sleep

Tags: mstest, async-ctp, thread-sleep

I have a long running task method, using Sleep

```
public Task LongRunning() {
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(
        () => {
            Trace.TraceInformation("Start Sleep");

            Thread.Sleep(10000);

            Trace.TraceInformation("End Sleep");
        });
}
```

This is called by my test, and it works fine

```
[TestMethod]
public void SimpleContinueWith() {
    Trace.TraceInformation("Start");

    LongRunning()
        .ContinueWith(
            t => Trace.TraceInformation("End")
        ).Wait();
}

> QTAgent32.exe Information: 0 : Start
> QTAgent32.exe Information: 0 : Start Sleep
> QTAgent32.exe Information: 0 : End Sleep
> QTAgent32.exe Information: 0 : End
```

But using async/await the test falls straight through

```
[TestMethod]
public async void SimpleAwait() {
    Trace.TraceInformation("Start");

    await LongRunning();

    Trace.TraceInformation("End");
}

> QTAgent32.exe Information: 0 : Start
> QTAgent32.exe Information: 0 : Start Sleep
```

Why is that then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MSTest cannot (currently) handle asynchronous tests. I'm not sure if Microsoft is going to add this for the final release. **Update: VS11 Beta did add support for async unit tests; see below.**

You can unit test asynchronous methods by providing an async context yourself. There's some included in the Async CTP (*Microsoft Visual Studio Async CTP\Samples\(C# Testing) Unit Testing\AsyncTestUtilities*), or you can use one I wrote called [AsyncContext](http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AsyncContext).

Using `AsyncContext`, your test can be written as:

```
[TestMethod]
public void SimpleAwait() {
  AsyncContext.Run(async () =>
  {
    Trace.TraceInformation("Start");

    await LongRunning();

    Trace.TraceInformation("End");
  });
}
```

**Update, 2012-02-05:** Another option is the new [AsyncUnitTests library](http://asyncunittests.codeplex.com/). Install that NuGet package, change your `TestClass` to `AsyncTestClass`, and your async unit tests can be written much more naturally:

```
[TestMethod]
public async void SimpleAwait() {
  Trace.TraceInformation("Start");

  await LongRunning();

  Trace.TraceInformation("End");
}
```

**Update, 2012-06-06:** If you update to VS2012 Beta, you can define asynchronous unit tests; they just have to return `Task`:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task SimpleAwait() {
  Trace.TraceInformation("Start");

  await LongRunning();

  Trace.TraceInformation("End");
}
```

Comment: Super, thanks, installed the nuget package http://nuget.org/List/Packages/Nito.AsyncEx

Comment: btw, the reason I was writing the test was because I have an Async method which calls Parallel.ForEach and recurses - which doesn't work with async/await, in the same way as the tests above behave, ie get called and never come back. The AsyncContext fixes this - thanks again